# Adobe LiveCycle: Changing binding properties of fields at runtime

Tags: binding, livecycle

I have a PDF order form that lists hundreds of product items (inside read only text fields) and they each have an associated "Quantity" field. Is it possible to dynamically change the binding property of the "Quantity" field from "No data binding" to "Use name" based on whether the user has entered a Quantity? I would like to accomplish this to limit the file size of the XML file that gets submitted from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the binding at runtime will not work unless you rerender/reinitialize the form.

You can however use javascript on field exit events or pre-submit event to create XML data elements for quantities. Or use bindings but remove empty xml nodes before submit if you're trying to limit the XML size.

Check out the XFA scripting guide, in particular `xfa.datasets.createNode` function for creating XML nodes.